# How to Determine if a Triangle contains a specific point?

Tags: c#, graphics, 2d, linear-algebra

I've question to ask you guys...

Now lets say I've a virtual grid, and I have junction points on these virtual grid as show below

[image: Junction Points On Virtual Grid]

Now lets say I've drawn a triangle onto this virtual grid as show below

[image: Triangle with Points]

Now I wonder if any of the virtual grid's point is **contained** by the triangle...
How can I achieve this using C#.Net?

**Note**: I also know the points for the triangles, and the question is for 2D plane..

My best regards...

Comment: Question: Is this always a triangle containing a right angle?

Comment: No, it's not... What would you suggest if my answer was yes?

Comment: Not quite sure ;) But simple trigonometry on the triangle itself would allow you to calculate certain lines fairly fast.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Define your triangle as [GraphicsPath](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.drawing.drawing2d.graphicspath.aspx) and use [GraphicsPath.IsVisible(Point)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/d20k495d.aspx) method  to determine if this path contains the point.

Comment: Which uses a floodfill-like algorithm and thus is quite inefficient for simple geometries.

Answer (score 8):

I found a general approach to find if a point is within a triangle [here](http://www.blackpawn.com/texts/pointinpoly/default.html)

hope this helps

Comment: Turns out, this is the same solution I came up with below, but explained much better - +1

Answer (score 4):

- Say your triangle consists of points A,B and C
- Say you want to test point P for being inside the triangle

Being inside the triangle can be resolved as being to the same side (left or right) of all of the vectors AB, BC and CA. So you

- Create 3d vectors AB, BC, CA with z=0 (this has to be done only once per triangle)
- Create 3d vectors AP, BP, CP with z=0 (this has to be done once per point P)
- Calculate p=ABxAP, q=BCxBP and r=CAxCP (this has to be done once per point P)

Your point is inside the triangle, if p,q and r have the same sign on their z coordinates